# What is the importance of the xml declarations in deployment descriptors?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

Anyone know if they are important at all?  I am trying to create a WebLogic 12c application.  For the web.xml file, is this xml declaration ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
```

And this is my application.xml declaration:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" version="7">
```

If instead of version="7", I had version="5" like this, would it matter?  Does this tell it to use Java EE 5 specs or since I'm using 12c, it will be Java EE 7 no matter what:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
```

Comment: Great answers, but none answered this specific question:  If instead of version="7", I had the version="5" declaration, does WebLogic use Java EE 5 specs or since I'm using 12c, will it still be Java EE 7 no matter what?  Assume that the code does not use any features about Java EE 5.  Some answers seem to point to it using the Java EE 5 spec, but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Before JavaEE 7, all the common annotations, as `@Path` or `@WebListener` had to be listed in the deployment descriptor instead. With the introduction of these annotations you cann now leave it up to them to do the class-role bindings.

But... They are *not* obsolete, `web.xml` has precedence and will override the annotations. This makes it easy for the coder to set some settings for development and testing purposes and let the deployer set it to something more "deployable" without touching the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good principle that called "fail earlier." This means, that the earlier you can detect the error the better. And also once the error is detected report it, do not continue. It is because if you continue to use bad data or run in bad state the damage will be higher than if you fail immediately.

Example:
Think about the system that transfers money from account A to B. The final amount is calculated. Bug in calculation caused that the amount is negative. What is better once you detect this: to fail to to continue and in fact add some amount of money to account A and remove from account B although opposite operation was required?

The same is concerning the schema in XML. If application (in your case Java EE container fails to validate the XML it is better than if it deploys your application incorrectly. Incorrect deployment may later cause the bug like one described above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using Java EE 7 - use the new deployment descriptors. The namespaces have changed.

You can compare the differences between http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd and http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd

A summary of the changes is documented here - https://antoniogoncalves.org/2013/06/04/java-ee-7-deployment-descriptors/

The application server *might* accept your app even with the old descriptors, but it might be just for backward-compatibility. If you are sure your application is Java EE 7 based, it is strongly encouraged to use the new descriptor namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it matters. Different schemas will have different capabilities. My answer applies to schemas in general.

There are a lot of variables, but it's possible a certain schema is not compatible with a certain dependency. For instance (Completely fictional situation), let's say you're using Java EE version 5, and you import the version 7 schema.

Version 5 has an element called `foo`. `foo` takes an `id`. Version 7 added a new feature to `foo` and now it has a new parameter `name`.

You're using Java EE 5, which only has `foo(id)`, but in your XML you define

```
 <foo id="bar" name="bar"/>
```

which is perfectly valid XML, according to the schema. However, this is going to fail at runtime because in Java EE 5, `foo` cannot have a `name`.

I don't know about your specific situation, but in all cases, your schema version should match the version of your dependency. The best case is nothing bad happens. The worst case is something fails, and it's not apparent why.